# Linq Querying On Collection attributes and Matching all Children

Tags: linq, entity-framework, collections, children

I am working on this Query, it is taking me a while as I'm pretty new to Linq.

I have this two collections `c.l.ChoreTIs` and `c.r.ChoreTIs`.

I want to get all where `c.l.Chore.TIs.Name == c.r.ChoreTIs.Name` and not ALL of their parameters (Children) match on `parameterValue`.

I am pretty close but still have some issues

```
Dim Query = From l In c.l.ChoreTIs _
                            Join r In c.r.ChoreTIs On l.Name Equals r.Name _
                            Where (l.Parameters.All(Function(lp) r.Parameters.Any(Function(rp) lp.parameterValue = rp.parameterValue)))
                            Select New With {.lChore = l, .rChore = r}
```

The query works, but I am getting all `ChoreTIs` that match name even when not all `Parameters.parameterValue` match. I need to return all where NOT exactly ALL match.

I want just the ones ChoreTIs that match name but they don't have exactly the same amount of children (parameters) or one Parameter has a different `parameterValue`.

Is there a better way to do this? or how could I fix it?

Cheers

UPDATE:

```
Dim Query = From l In c.l.ChoreTIs _
                            Join r In c.r.ChoreTIs On l.Name Equals r.Name _
                            Where (l.Parameters.Count <> r.Parameters.Count) Or _
                                  ((l.Parameters.Count = r.Parameters.Count) And
                                  (l.Parameters.Select(Function(lp) lp.parameterValue).Except(r.Parameters.Select(Function(rp) rp.parameterValue)).Any()))
                            Select New With {.lChore = l, .rChore = r}
```

I got it to work, but I'd still be keen if someone has a better way to do it.

Comment: Do you want all of the `ChoreTIs` from both `c.l.*` & `c.r.*`, or just from one or the other?

Comment: I would like to have the two of them, like in two objects left and right as select l,c in that way I could manipulate the two of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use intersect :

```
var newData = c.l.ChoreTIs.Select(a => a.Name).Intersect(c.r.ChoreTIs.Select(s => s.Name));
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but I need to find those c.l and c.r ChoreTis that match names that also, match all their children in parameterValue and return the two objects. l and r.

Answer (score 0):

My VB syntax might not be 100% correct, but is this closer to what you want:

```
    Dim query = _
        From l In c.l.ChoreTIs _
        Join r In c.r.ChoreTIs On l.Name = r.Name _
        Where (l.Parameters.All(Function(lp) r.Parameters.Any(Function(rp) lp = rp)))
        New From _
        { _
            l, _
            r _
        }
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it is pretty close I've been testing it and I haven't got it to work yet. I used your query but It doesn't return any result and I should get 1 chore according to my testing. if I change the line "lp = rp" to lp.Equals(rp) I get nothing in return. if I change it to lp.parameterValue = rp.parameterValue I get two when I should be getting only one. Looking for a fix now. I Appreciate your help

Comment: Basically the wheare clause should return false when all Children (Parameters) from r match l in count and parameterValue.

Comment: I thought my VB syntax was a bit dodgy. I hope it helped though.

Comment: It did help but still not getting the results I expect. I'm getting the "ChoreTIs" but not JUST the ones that don't match exactly on Parameters count (Children) and Parameters.parmeterValue. Can't seem to find a way to get all ChoreTIs that don't have exactly the same collection of Parameters (Children) yet.